# Query does execute without errors, but returns no output

Tags: sql, postgresql

My query here has a sub-query in it but it returns no output, but in reality it has to give some output because I manually checked and output exists.I have posted the query below.

```
    select mac.mac_id,mac.mac1,mac.mac_type,record.soc_id
    from mso_charter.mac
    join record on mac.record_id = record.record_id
    where mac.mac_type='ethB' and record.soc_id IN (select soc from d);
```

Sample data is below

```
    mac_id mac1   mac_type record_id--- for table mac
    1      6142   ethA       1 
    2      6412   ethB       1
    3      2313   ethC       1

    record_id soc_id ---- for table record
     1          Qu132
     1          as432
     1          342aq

    soc --- for table d
    a12w2
    23we
    qw12
```

mso_charter is the schema name mac,d and record is the table name.

Comment: I think you need sample data and desired results.  If the query returns no results, it is because things don't match.

Comment: Your Postgres version and table definitions showing data types and constraints to begin with ...

Comment: Try query without `... and record.soc_id IN (select soc from d)` part and see if it gives any result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to all who tried helping me in this situation. I actually had did a very silly mistake.The reason I am posting the right answer is probably because if someone else in future get stuck in such a issue or something similar it would be helpful to them.

```
    select m.mac_id,m.mac,m.mac_type,r.soc_id
    from mso_charter.mac m
    join mso_charter.record r on m.record_id = r.record_id
   where m.mac_type = 'ethB' and r.soc_id IN (select d.soc_id from d);
```

Mistake was I had not mentioned the schema name while performing join and there were multiple tables named record in other schema's, it was just out of frustration we tend to forget small things which costed me few hours to work over.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your subquery is actually still a join and can be written that way:

```
select mac.mac_id,mac.mac1,mac.mac_type,record.soc_id
  from mso_charter.mac
       join record using(record_id)
       join d on record.soc_id = d.soc
where mac.mac_type='ethB';
```

As per the comment we still need a data set to reproduce and help.

Comment: So, this also has really nothing different from the way I have written my query ! But unfortunately both our approaches doesn't return any results

Answer (score 0):

None of your `record.soc_id` match any of your `d.soc_id`. So you get no row.

Also, you write `select soc from d`. `soc`, not `soc_id`. Typo or error?

Answer (score 0):

Should be select soc_id from d instead of select  `select soc from d`

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample data, `d` has a column `soc_id`.  That should be used for the comparison:

```
select m.mac_id, m.mac1, m.mac_type, r.soc_id
from mso_charter.mac m join
     record r
     on m.record_id = r.record_id
where m.mac_type = 'ethB' and
      r.soc_id in (select d.soc_id from d);
```

It is possible that ids look the same but are not, because of international characters, hidden characters, spaces in the wrong place, and so on.

If this doesn't work then try the following:

- Remove the `soc_id` condition and see if any rows match the first condition and `join`.
- If that still returns nothing, remove the entire `where` clause to see if anything matches the `join`.

Comment: there are many values matching the join and which works perfectly fine and I am not able to guess why r.soc_id in (select d.soc_id from d) is not working.Thats the only part not working